# PowerShell Iterate through array and if match copy-item

Tags: powershell-3.0

I would like to be able to look through an array and if a source directory contains a copy of the file required from the text file place a copy of the file into another folder.

```
$Source=get-content .\2cHotfix.txt
$Available=gci

foreach($item in $Source){
  $_ -match $Available;`
  Copy-Item $item .\InUse\*.*
}
```

> sample available output

```
gci -Include *.cab -Recurse| select -First 5  -ExpandProperty Name
```

> windows8-rt-kb2727528-x64_92649202b7e2269d8389cb4c196e97bb71ef244c.cab
>   windows8-rt-kb2729462-x64_98376c883f61da7ff61d61bed1ab2770c8cdde2c.cab
>   windows8-rt-kb2736693-x64_461a3322139f134f066bc66c209714f42ad7857f.cab
>   windows8-rt-kb2737084-x64_67da24ea41c8a42f75d09656713697f80f263a14.cab
>   windows8-rt-kb2742614-x64_791ea59ee9e2500a6d60d011544245c3af7de1e7.cab
>
> Sample source text file input.
>
> hotfixid
>
> KB2756872
>   KB2758246
>   KB2761094

Comment: Hi Joel, please can you post the output of the following two commands as they will probably make your question disambiguous:

"gci | select -First 5 -ExpandProperty Name"

AND

"gc .\2cHotfix.txt | Select -First 5"

Comment: updated original statement to include your 2 sample information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated after seeing the format of your file and the expected file names.

The first line skips the first two lines of 2cHotfix.txt as we don't want to try and match "Hotfixid" or a blank line. We then check to see if we have any files in the current directory that contain the line from sources (in the format KB#######) we are currently checking. If a file is found we then copy it to the ./InUse folder.

```
$Source=get-content .\2cHotfix.txt | select -Skip 2

foreach($item in $Source){
    $file = gci -filter $("*{0}*" -f $item)
    if ($file -ne $null)
    {
        Copy-Item $file .\InUse
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Dan I should have explained a bit further why I was using match. the text file contents are just installed patches I want to copy out a huge directory. so the contents of the file only contain the kb number. Like this.  
hotfixid                                                                                                                                                                                                              
KB2756872   So when I use it as a filter it states error the path is empty

Comment: Thanks, Dan. This works for copying files. It copies all files.                                        But what I was hoping to achieve was only matches from 2chotfix.txt were copied and not all files. That is why I tried the match operator.

Comment: Hi Joel, Unfortunately I can't replicate the bahaviour of copying all the files without first adding all the KB numbers to 2cHotfix.txt,

Comment: Thanks for your persistence in this matter.                                       A way to replicate the behavior is to have the $source file 2cHotfix.txt contain a KB245  and in the directory where you run GCI have a couple of files created. Have a directory with a file named SDFD-KB245-jkj.cab and one KB111111.cab. One in the 2cHotfix KB245 should match SDFD-KB245-jkj.cab  in directly and copy the file to the "InUse" folder.

Comment: HI Joel, I've done a screen capture of the code running for me. What's in the video is my interpretation of what you wanted. (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-kN4kPOjEdDZmVmM0psQnFIbnc/view?usp=sharing)

Could you please let me know, what you would have expected to be in the InUse folder given the 2cHotfix.txt file in my video. Cheers, Dan [p.s. The video is in better quality if you download it first rather than use the web player]

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for your persistence in this issue. This was excellent response and solved the problem. When I tested again it copied all files so I modified the files in the directory. It seems there is some kind of a limit within PowerShell that is smaller than with the file system. When I delete even as few as 4 characters. Checked the lengths of files and non greater than 38 characters so it should work without issue.                                                                                    BTW How did you create the video? That was awesome. Thanks so much for sticking with this.

Comment: Hi Joel, not a problem. Glad it helped. A discontinued microsoft product called Expression Encoder 4 includes a screen capture utility (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24601) however as it's discontinued the video is limited to capturing 10 minutes at a time though.